# Active perl multiple sockets

Tags: perl, sockets

Alright so im having an issue with creating multiple sockets in active perl.
Heres an example of what im trying to do here.

```
for($i=0;$i<$botcount;$i++){
my ($socket[$I],$client_socket[$I]);
my $socket[$I] = new IO::Socket::Socks(
ConnectAddr=>$chatip,
ConnectPort=>$chatport,
);
}
```

Un fortunately this gives me an error.

I know I could rename it but that would make so much un nessasary space.
Can someone help me out here?

Comment: You need `use strict; use warnings;` first of all and you need to create your array outside of the for loop and finally, the variable $i is different to $I as perl is case sensitive

Answer (score 0):

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl -w
 use strict;
 use diagnostics; #this will explain warnings/errors

 #declare your variables here
 my ($botcount, $chatport, $chatip);
 my @client_socket;
 my @socket;
 foreach my $i (0..$botcount){
      $socket[$i] = new IO::Socket::Socks(
           ConnectAddr => $chatip,
           ConnectPort => $chatport
      );
 }
```